# Count of values from list in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a column

```
df['COL_1']
```

and a list of numbers

```
num_range = list(range(200,281, 5))
```

The columns contains either words such as `UNREADABLE` `NOT_PASSIVE` or some values present in the list above, so `200` `205` `210` etc or nothing.

I am trying to get a sum of how many rows in that column contains a number in the range given.

What I have tried:

```
df['COL_1'].value_counts(num_range)
```

I am not sure what else to try, the various trials I have done similar to the above have all failed.
I'm new to python, any guidance is highly appreciated.

Python 2.7 and pandas 0.24.2

EDIT:

I was getting errors, as other users have mentioned, my data was not numeric. Fixed this with `.astype` or alternatively, redifining target_range as so:

```
target_range = map(str, range(200, 281, 5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after the whole sum, and are not interested in the breakout of individual counts,

```py
target_range = range(200, 281, 5)
df["COL_1"].isin(target_range).sum()
```

Notice that you do not need to cast the `range` object to a `list`.

If you want the breakout of value counts, see @Corralien's answer.

Details: `pandas.DataFrame.isin()` is a function which returns a boolean mask.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> # Data provided by Corralien
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'COL_1': ['UNREADABLE', 200, 'NOT_PASSIVE', 205, 210, 200, '', 210, 180, 170, '']})
>>> target_range = range(200, 281, 5)
>>> df.isin(target_range)
    COL_1
0   False
1    True
2   False
3    True
4    True
5    True
6   False
7    True
8   False
9   False
10  False
```

Notice I'm using `df.isin()` instead of `df["COL_1"].isin()`. If you have multiple columns in your DataFrame that you want to perform this operation on, you can pass a `list` of column names. If you want to perform this operation on your entire DataFrame, you can simply use `df.isin()`.

The `.isin()` method returns a boolean mask. Since `bool` is a subtype of `int`, you can simply call `sum()` on the resulting DataFrame to sum up all the 1s and 0s to get your final tally of all the rows which match your criterion.

Comment: I'm getting a very strange error, when I print out `df["COL_1"].isin(target_range).sum()` it returns 0. So I check `df[COL_1].isin(target_range)` and it returns false for all the values. But when I print out that column, I can clearly see values such as 205, 230 etc. Why would I get such a strange error? Many thanks for your help

Comment: For that you'll need to edit your OP to show your actual data. Are your numeric values not actually numeric? Really not easy for us to tell without seeing the actual data.

Comment: Indeed, sorry about the hassle, I'm quite new to all this. Updated my original question with the fix to my error in case it ever helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL_1': ['UNREADABLE', 200, 'NOT_PASSIVE', 205, 210, 
                             200, '', 210, 180, 170, '']})

out = df.loc[df['COL_1'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
                        .isin(num_range), 'COL_1'] \
        .value_counts()
```

```
>>> out
200    2
210    2
205    1
Name: COL_1, dtype: int64

>>> out.sum()
5
```

Comment: It's not necessary to cast or coerce, you can directly do `df["COL_1"].isin(target_range).sum()` and you'll get the count of rows which have a value in the target range.

Comment: I may have been too presumptuous about OP's data. They may indeed need to cast and coerce, if their data isn't already numeric as I had originally assumed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a column in a DataFrame as a list of items and also have another list of values. and you want to count how many items from dataframe column exist in the list. right?

so use this:

```
count = 0
for i in df['COL_1']:
    if i in num_range:
        count +=1
```

in each iteration on your column, if the value exist in the list, count variable added by one.